# Why do diagonal entries of odd potencies of adjacency matrices of forests sum up to zero?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I came across the statement that the trace (sum of diagonal entries) of an odd potency of an adjacency matrix of a forest is always zero. I have tried out a few options and it seems to be correct for forests or trees but not for other graphs, e.g.:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $A^3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\ 4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

While if I add one edge to create a circle:

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B^3 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 0 \\ 4 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Can someone explain to me why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph, then $A^n_{ij}$ counts the number of paths of length $n$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.  If you are in a forest, because there are no cycles, every step along a path is either one step closer or one step father away from any particular vertex.  Because of this, if we start at vertex $i$, we will alternate between an even distance away and an odd distance away.  In particular, at odd times, we are an odd distance away, and therefore NOT back at our starting point.  So all the diagonal entries of $A^n$ are $0$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Okay, I think I am mostly following you. So, basically in the case of even distances, the path goes the same way back to the vertex that it took away from it? E.g., A^2 has one path (among others) of distance 2 from 0 to 1 to 0 again. Which obviously doesn't work with odd distances.

Comment: @Max Well, not necessarily the same way.  For example, if you consider $\mathbb N$ as a graph, we could start at $1$ and take the path $1,2,3,4,3,4,3,2,3,2,1$.  But between any two connected points, there is only one shortest path, and you are either returning along it, or you are going out further, and so your distance away from the starting points either goes up by 1 or down by 1 every time you move.  This isn't true on, say, a triangle.

Comment: @Max In retrospect, I think when you say "the path goes the way way back", perhaps you are referring to the fact that there is exactly one direction closer, but you are not suggesting that first you go (only) further away and then you go (only) closer?  Regardless, at any point, there is only one way to go closer, and possibly many ways to go further away, and so the parity of the distance ALWAYS changes.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean that first you go only away and then only closer but that in your example path $1,2,3,4,3,4,3,2,3,2,1$ the edges leading back to $1$ are edges we have also used to get away from it. But thanks for further elaborating!